# Javascript Opera - Turn off document body scroll (temporarily)

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, opera

I've got a pic viewer that uses the mouse wheel to zoom.  Works fine except in Opera, the wheel scrolls the page first, then fires the wheel event, which is less than desirable (since now the picture has moved up or down the page).

So, I want to turn off the body scroll while the viewer is active.  Shouldn't be too hard, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the JavaScript that scrolls also call event.preventDefault()? This should work, though I haven't tested it recently myself.

Answer (score 0):

possibly this might work?

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'` but no luck.  Will try again though.